# Accessing Authenticated User Info in ApplicationDbContext class (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have an ApplicationDbContext class :
`ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>` where I have override methods on `SaveChanges` && `SaveChangesAsync` to include the `UpdateAuditEntities` method. What i want is to get the user-name / email of the logged in user so every entity that inherits from IAuditableEntity is tagged with the user who created / updated the entity.

```
        private void UpdateAuditEntities()
        {
            var CurrentUserId = ???;
            var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));


            foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
            {
                var entity = (IAuditableEntity)entry.Entity;
                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                    entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUserId;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                }

                entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUserId;
            }
        }
```

Doing my research, i found a good article [here](http://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/) but I have a DesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation like below:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Reset();

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();

            //IUserResolverService userResolverService = ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.CreateScope()

            builder.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"], b => b.MigrationsAssembly("SybrinApp.Pro"));

            return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

The suggested [solution](http://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/) means my ApplicationDbContext will need `UserResolverService` to instantiate. How can i go about injecting `UserResolverService` into the DesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation or is there another way to get the currently logged in user in my `class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>`

Comment: Where are you using ApplicationUser class? in controller?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question. Do you mean where am I trying to access the ApplicationUser from? I want the user info in my override methods. `public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            UpdateAuditEntities();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }` the `UpdateAuditEntities` method is the one posted in the question. So this is in the ApplicationDbContext class which is am implementation of `IdentityDbContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, have changed my answer. I have borrowed from this [url](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/20/idesigntimedbcontextfactory-and-dependency-injection-a-love-story/) to demonstrate what you can do.

1) first of all create a DependencyResolver class to wrap up the DI
Note that I am assuming that your userResolveService is implementing an IUserResolveService

```
 public class DependencyResolver
{
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }
    public string CurrentDirectory { get; set; }

    public DependencyResolver()
    {
        // Set up Dependency Injection
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register any DI you need here
        services.AddTransient<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();

    }
}
```

2) In your DesignTimeDbContextFactory, replace the commented out line with:

```
var resolver = new DependencyResolver();
IUserResolverService svc = resolver.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IUserResolverService))
 as UserResolverService;
```

Then go ahead and call as you need

Comment: this won't work as SaveChanges has an implementation in IdentityDbContext which am just overriding meaning i can't pass parameters / change SaveChanges' signature. Unless i am missing something.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just had to add the `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` to the `ConfigureServices` method.